# Read access violation error when declaring a class with a dereferenced pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers, debugging, memory-management

I am trying to write a function that creates a class object from two pointers to other class objects, but I keep getting a read access violation error.
My program has three classes:

```
class A {
    public:
        A(const A& a2); // Special copy constructor
    private:
        int a = 0;
}

class B {
    public:
        B(const B& b2); // Special copy constructor
    private:
        int b = 0;
}

class C {
    public:
        A* aPtr;
        B* bPtr;
}
```

What I am trying to do, is to have a function that takes a pointer to an A object and a B object, and then dereferences these into a C-instance. It is important that the objects themselves get copied since it is for multithreading purposes. The function is for example:

```
void foo(A* ptrA, B* ptrB){
    C* ptrC = new C();
    *ptrC->aPtr = *A;
    *ptrC->bPtr = *B;
}
```

But this gives me a read access violation error.
What am I doing wrong? I know that objects themselves get copied without error, so I think it has something to do with how i declare ptrC or dereference ptrC->A and ptrC->B. Am I right about this?
What is a possible solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *But this gives me a read access violation error* -- Please post a [mcve].

Comment: `*ptrC->A = *A;` is a new twist on the three star programmer.

Comment: You never initialize `C::aPtr` or '`C::bPtr`.

Comment: @ FrançoisAndrieux sorry, my bad. I'll fix it.

Comment: Actually, they are initialized, but to `nullptr` due to using the parentheses: `C* ptrC = new C();`.  Otherwise you have a point -- without the parentheses, those members are not initialized.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Indeed, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> A(const A& a2); // Special copy constructor
> ```

What you call a "special copy constructor" is commonly known as a converting constructor.

> But this gives me a read access violation error. What am I doing
> wrong?

> ```
> C* ptrC = new C();
> ```

This creates a dynamic object and value initialises it. The pointers that are members are value initialised to null.

> ```
> *ptrC->aPtr = *A;
> *ptrC->bPtr = *B;
> ```

Here, you indirect through those null pointers and write to the memory. This results in undefined behaviour.

> What is a possible solution?

Don't indirect through null pointers. Perhaps storing A and B objects instead of pointers within the C object would fit better to your design?

Answer (score 0):

yes pretty much try:

```
void foo(A* ptrA, B* ptrB){
    C* ptrC = new C();
    ptrC->aPtr = ptrA;
    ptrC->bPtr = ptrB;
}
```

instead
(and try to avoid pointers next time they never help you out with anything)

Comment: Welcome, perhaps explain why your solution is correct. Personally I find pointers are useful for many things.

Comment: yeah sorry so basically the original question was trying to set a pointer of the class rather than simply passing the actual instances of the class which makes no sense what so ever